# How to add more values in one editText Android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, average

I have an application which calculates 2 simple averages and 1 complex average. The problem is that the average is calculated from 9 values entered in 9 edit texts, and even if the application is working perfect, the edittexts on other size of screen are not arranged anymore. I tried several things to make it work, but nothing so far, so, I decided that it would be much easier to have only 1 edittext, in the case of simple averages, and the button. In the edittext to enter as much as values as you want, and after every value entered to click on a "+" button, and then, when you entered the all values you wanted, to press an "=" button which shows in the same edittext where you entered the values the average of the values you entered. In the case of the complex average, to have 2 edit text and like in the first, to calculate the average from the values entered in the first, making a simple average, and with the value from the second edittext to calculate the complex average. Hope you understood exactly and could help me with this. Thanks a lot !!!

Here is my:

**Medii.java**

```
    package com.cngcnasaud.orar;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Medii extends Activity {

public static ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();
double sum, res;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.medii);

    final EditText editTextNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNum);
    Button buttona = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button999);
    Button buttonCalc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1000);
    final TextView textViewRes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewRes);

    buttona.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             String numCatch=editTextNum.getText().toString().trim();
                if(numCatch.length() != 0){
                       num.add(numCatch);
                    editTextNum.setText("");
                }
                textViewRes.setText("The average is ");
        }
    });

    buttonCalc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            for(int i=0;i<num.size();i++){
                sum = Integer.parseInt(num.get(i)) + sum;
            }
            res = sum/num.size();
            textViewRes.setText("The average is "+format.format(res));
            res = 0;
            sum = 0;
            num.clear();
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: when you have a list of variables named *1-36 that does not fit on your screen, it is time to review your code structure.

Comment: It is fitting perfect, but if the size of screen is smaller or bigger, it's not anymore perfect.

Comment: `variables that does not fit on your screen`,  I'm only meaning in your code.

Comment: I got your point. But I decided to try doing it like this because it could be easier for users to use it. Hope you understood my point too. Thanks !

Comment: the way your code is organized has nothing to do with your users.

Comment: anyway, the issue you're asking about seems to be related to layout. If so, it could be of some help to post your layout file.

Comment: You didn't understand my idea. I don't want to help me with my layout codes or how to arrange it, or how to fit it, I want you to help me creating the edittexts as I said in the first post. Sorry for confussion. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see where you issue lies, then. It seems quite unrelated to your current code. Just put a TextView, an EditText, a pair of buttons, store your values every time you press +, and there you have it.

Comment: This is what I want to do. The codes I posted are for how the app works now, but I want to do it how you described... and the problem is I don't know how to store the values and how to detect how many values I've entered..

Comment: I have edited the first post with what I did so far. I created the simple average and works perfect, only that it does not show the exact average, I mean, beetwen 9 and 10, the average is 9.5, but my application is showing 9. Why and how to create the complex average? Thx!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I got it right, but you could use the method .split("+") to split your input string into an Array of strings, which are you numbers. Then cast each string separately to int, and continue as before. If you want the answer after the "=", concatenate the input string and result string.

Comment: I did it.. i've edited the first post. But now I'm trying to deal with the complex average.. This average is calculated from a simple average * 3 + another value entered by user, all divided to 4.

Comment: I would not do that. For one, using a virtual keypad, you'll probably want to restrict to numbers, which usually does not include `+`. Secondly, an actual on screen `+` button allows you to build a list of items and verify them individually immediately.